# How to configure Python Script to run as a daemon

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, daemon

I have a couple webservers sitting behind a loadbalancer, and i found "watcher.py" here: https://github.com/splitbrain/Watcher

I chose this script for several reasons: recursive through folders, lots of triggering options

Anyways, I will be using this to sync web content between load balanced servers. Is there a way to ensure that this script will run at bootup?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the easiest way to handle applications like this is to install `supervisord` and then use that to start, monitor, and collect output from the your script.

Here's a sample supervisor config file:

```
[program:watcher]
command = /usr/bin/python /path/to/watcher.py
stdout_logfile = /var/log/watcher-stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
stdout_logfile_backups = 5
stderr_logfile = /var/log/watcher-stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
stderr_logfile_backups = 5
```

Comment: Documentation for supervisord for my distro (ubuntu) is full of holes, but with a bit of troubleshooting wasnt too hard to figure out. @EEAA , your solution was exactly the solution i was looking for, it works great! thank you for your help, i would upvote, but i do not have the reputation to do so.

Comment: @Ace - excellent, glad to be of help.

Comment: Perfect except I needed to add `start` to the command:

    command = /usr/bin/python /dati/bin/watcher.py start